# Firefox console - no element found - AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am retrieving a set of dates from the database in the PHP and encoding it as a JSON. I am trying to retrieve the json in my javascript file so that the dates can be used to disable  dates in the datepicker UI.

When I run the project in Firefox and inspect elements, I am getting this error:

```html
no element found checkDates.php:32:3
```

When I run the php file, the output is what is expected with no errors.

**checkDates.php**

```js
<?php
//Set document mime type... this is important since you want to return json not text!
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "user";
$dbname = "ebooking";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "select booking_date from booking";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$checkDates = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $checkDates[] = $row['booking_date'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($checkDates);
$conn->close();
?>
```

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


</head>
<body>
Date:
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
<script>
    var badDates //= ["21-03-2016","31-03-2016","31-03-2016","30-03-2016"];
    $.getJSON('checkDates.php', function(json){badDates=json,
        console.dir(badDates);});


    /*$.getJSON( "checkDates.php", function(json) {
       console.log( "success" );
    }).done(function() {
       console.log( "second success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
       console.log( "complete" );

    });*/


    $(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date ), badDates) > -1)
                {
                    return [false,"Unavailable","Booked"];
                }
                else
                {
                    return [true,"Available","Not Booked"];
                }
            }
        });
    })

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 1: add a semicolon after `var badDates ` 2: try calling your php from the command line and see what it returns

Comment: This is what the php returns    ["21-03-2016","31-03-2016","31-03-2016","30-03-2016"]

Comment: Also note you need to return json if no dates found or expect that as `fail()`

Comment: @charlietfl I don't entirely understand. how would that be implemented?

Comment: `["21-03-2016","31-03-2016","31-03-2016","30-03-2016"] ` is an array, `{ dates: ["21-03-2016","31-03-2016","31-03-2016","30-03-2016"] }` is JSON and can be used as badDates.dates

Comment: Probably best to return empty array so `$.inArray` doesn't get passed `undefined`

Comment: @mplungjan Okay. So in what way would I need to modify my array in the php file?

Comment: @charlietfl are you able to demonstrate that please?